# Am I imagining things? List being made a reference to a second list instead of being made a copy of the second list

Tags: c#

This code seems to be making `_cleanRepositoryCollection` a reference to `_currentTextFile.RepositoryCollection` instead of making it a copy of `_currentTextFile.RepositoryCollection`:

```
_cleanRepositoryCollection = _currentTextFile.RepositoryCollection;
```

The datatype is `List<Repository>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you're not imagining things.  That stores a reference to the list returned by  `_currentTextFile.RepositoryCollection`.

Now, this may be a reference to `_currentTextFile`'s internal `RepositoryCollection` list, or it may be a copy -- it depends on the implementation of the `RepositoryCollection` property.

If you want to ensure that you have a copy, you need to make the copy yourself.

Comment: Why is this storing a reference? When I take two strings and do the same thing I don't end up with a reference.
Is this because strings are immutable?

Comment: Actually you do. string s1 = "blah"; string s2 = s1; Object.ReferenceEquals(s1, s2); // is true

Comment: That's right. It's only when you CHANGE the string that it will create a copy. Yes, it is because they are immutable.

Answer (score 2):

Working as intended.

Try `_cleanRepositoryCollection = new List<Repository>(_currentTextFile.RepositoryCollection);`

Comment: This still seems to result in _cleanRepositoryCollection being a reference to _currentTextFile.RepositoryCollection.

Comment: @Justin: It won't - you would be able to add or remove items from one list without affecting the other. However, the elements themselves will still be references to `Repository` objects, assuming `Repository` is a class... so if you make a change *within* one of those `Repository` objects, it doesn't matter whether you access it via one of the lists or some other way - you'll still see the change.

Comment: True.  Deep copies can be a pain. In order to prevent what Jon mentioned you'd have to create new objects and copy values recursively for every Repository, and every object contained within them.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, that's the first thing any .NET developer should learn - the differences between [reference types and value types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ewxz6et.aspx) and the reference vs copy behaviors they exhibit.

Having said that, if the collection is not intended to be modified by code outside of the class, the internal list should not be exposed directly through a property. You can make a true clone of the list just by doing:

```
private List<Foo> internalList;

public List<Foo> RepositoryCollection {
    get {
        return new List<Foo>(interalList);
    }
}
```

Or if you just want to return a read-only wrapper to the caller so that they cannot modify your internal structure, you can do:

```
private List<Foo> internalList;
private ReadOnlyCollection<Foo> externalList;

public ReadOnlyCollection<Foo> RepositoryCollection {
    get {
        if (externalList == null) {
            externalList = internalList.AsReadOnly();
        }
        return externalList;
    }
}
```

In the second example, the returned collection is a read-only wrapper but it is not a snapshot at the time AsReadOnly was called. If you added an item to internalList, it would be reflected in externalList.

Answer (score 1):

List is a reference type. Hence in assigning it to _cleanRepositoryCollection you are assigning a reference to the same instance not copying the list (which in most scenarios would be inefficient).

I would suggest that the class you use for _currentTextFile should expose a CleanRepositoryCollection property that internally copies the collection (try new List(_currentTextFile.RepositoryCollection); as suggested in one of the other answers) and exposes IEnumerable. That ensures that the clients are not using an interface that can modify the collection and that they can't get around it by casting. Modifying the collection should be performed using appropriate business methods on _currentTextFile.